# Concatenate an incrementing variable to a cell with formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to loop a variable and it must be combined with a value from a cell with formula. 
This is what I have but I can't get it to work. The compiler either read it as a string or an error.

```
Counter=1
variable=1
For No1 = 41 To 48
Worksheets("Data").Cells(32 + No1, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=Concatenate(R[-" & Counter & "]C,""-"",""L"",variable)"
variable = variable + 1
Counter = Counter + 1
Next No1
```

> R[-" & Counter & "]C = Formula from parts of code but there is a value "R00S01". Result should give **R00S01-L1,R00S01-L2,R00S01-L3...** . I got **=Concatenate(D1133,"-","L",a)** from the code above and excel doesn't recognise it.

I had tried to put some quotes and & around but it still doesn't give me what I want. It will work if I didn't put variable into it.

```
Counter=1
For No1 = 41 To 48
Worksheets("Data").Cells(32 + No1, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=Concatenate(R[-" & Counter & "]C,""-"",""L"")"
Counter = Counter + 1
Next No1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove double quotes from `"variable"`.

```
Worksheets("Data").Cells(32 + No1, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=Concatenate(R[-" & Counter & "]C,""-"",""L""," & variable & ")"
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot, my bad that I didn't find this solved.